# CentOS 7 - Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, centos

I tried to install the docker in **CentOS 7** and got daemon error. I tried all the methods available on the internet for installation and for debugging but none really worked! I even tried to install older versions of docker that didn't work either.

**SELinux** is Disabled.

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

**docker version**

```
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: 
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

**systemctl status docker.service -l**

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-04-10 18:00:02 CEST; 49min ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 4510 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current --init-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current --seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $ADD_REGISTRY $BLOCK_REGISTRY $INSECURE_REGISTRY $REGISTRIES (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4510 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 10 18:00:01 ns3138286 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Apr 10 18:00:01 ns3138286 dockerd-current[4510]: time="2020-04-10T18:00:01.506877169+02:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 4522"
Apr 10 18:00:02 ns3138286 dockerd-current[4510]: time="2020-04-10T18:00:02.514107274+02:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded."
Apr 10 18:00:02 ns3138286 dockerd-current[4510]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
Apr 10 18:00:02 ns3138286 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 10 18:00:02 ns3138286 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 10 18:00:02 ns3138286 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 10 18:00:02 ns3138286 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Comment: You may need to make sure the port is open. There's a section in this video that'll step you through that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIp84wEl3uo

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to provide an exact solution to this question without more details, however, the error message is clear:

> 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host

Please note:

> To configure Docker to use the overlay storage driver your Docker host must be running version 3.18 of the Linux kernel (preferably
>   newer) with the overlay kernel module loaded.

Check the kernel version with `uname -r`

If you have installed a new kernel since installing docker, try rebooting your machine.

***If*** you do not explicitly need overlay, you can also specify storage drivers in the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file - 'devicemapper' was the preferred storage driver for kernels that do not support overlay.

Comment: Thank you for this! I was managed to install docker through official documentation with the latest version! However, it didn't work before!

Comment: @NoorQureshi glad to hear!